# SELECT TOP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

How can I do this in MySQL?

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM table
```

What's the simplest way to do it without running to separate queries (if possible)?

Comment: Do you want the 50th percentile or half the rows?

Comment: @Phil I want half the rows. Basically I want to select the first half and do something with in and then select the 2nd half and do something with it. Which is why i want it to be dynamic. I don't want to store the number of rows and then divide by 2 or anything like that.

Comment: In what order though? What defines "half"?

Comment: @Phil I'll sort them by alphabetical order ascending. Half meaning if I have 80 rows sorted A-Z I want to be able to select the first 40.

Comment: [Convert SQL Server query to MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5522462/569436)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson You sure that's the easiest way to do it? Seems like overkill. There has to be a simpler way.

Comment: When it comes to MySQL I am not sure of anything. The answer seemed related to this question. The technique used is the same as simulating the use of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no TOP n PERCENT syntax in MySQL.

You will have to emulate it as follows

First here is a sample table

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists mytable;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> create table mytable (id int not null auto_increment primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable values (),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),();
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
+----+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

You emulate it with this code:

```
set @percent = 50;
select floor(count(1) * @percent / 100.0) into @pct from mytable;
set @sqlstmt = concat('select * from mytable limit ',@pct);
prepare stmt from @sqlstmt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Here is that code executed:

```
mysql> set @percent = 50;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select floor(count(1) * @percent / 100.0) into @pct from mytable;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @sqlstmt = concat('select * from mytable limit ',@pct);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> prepare stmt from @sqlstmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> execute stmt;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
+----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> deallocate prepare stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score -1):

> ***I am sharing logic here***

Step 1 :: find total no of rows in table

var a = select count(*) in table_name

Step 2 ::  find 50% value of var a

var a = (var a / 2)

step 3 :: mysql query with row limits

select * from table_name limit

Comment: Why are you answering this question? It's long since been answered to the asker's satisfaction, and so far as I can tell, this answer doesn't add any extra value beyond what was already provided.